# Drag an object along a bezier curve using ThreeJs

Tags: three.js, bezier, curve, clamp

Using threesJs. I'm trying to move an object along a bezier curve (idealy beziercurve3).
My purpose is to move a little point by mouse and then after use this point to cut this curve in two,
or start an other curve3 attached to this point.

From what I search before I suppose I should use something like `clamp_to_curve` function.

I saw that Line3 got `closestPointTPoint` Is it a good idea to do the same with a bezier curve?
Maybe `getPoint` and `getPointAt` from `curve` can help but I don't know how to use them. After searching for a while I fill a little bite lost.
What is the best way to start this ?

Comment: Can you rephrase that as a problem statement that has a programming solution? Because "I want to do X, how do I do that?" is [not on-topic](/help/on-topic) and far better posted on a three.js user forum such as https://discourse.threejs.org/ - remember that Stackoverflow is not a general help forum, if your question can't be written in the form "I'm trying to understand this behaviour in programming language X after reading as much as I can" or "I wanted to do A, wrote code B, expected C but got D instead, and already tried debugging/the following things [...]" then it's probably not for SO.